# SEAM exception, can anyone tell me why its happening?

Tags: exception, seam

Can anyone tell me why this happens?

```
Jul 20, 2010 9:24:13 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class javassist.bytecode.StackMapTable$Writer from class org.jboss.seam.util.ProxyFactory
 at org.jboss.seam.util.ProxyFactory.makeConstructor(ProxyFactory.java:803)
 at org.jboss.seam.util.ProxyFactory.makeConstructors(ProxyFactory.java:685)
 at org.jboss.seam.util.ProxyFactory.make(ProxyFactory.java:565)
 at org.jboss.seam.util.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:346)
 at org.jboss.seam.util.ProxyFactory.createClass2(ProxyFactory.java:325)
 at org.jboss.seam.util.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:284)
 at org.jboss.seam.Component.createProxyFactory(Component.java:2426)
 at org.jboss.seam.Component.getProxyFactory(Component.java:1513)
 at org.jboss.seam.Component.wrap(Component.java:1504)
 at org.jboss.seam.Component.instantiateJavaBean(Component.java:1442)
 at org.jboss.seam.Component.instantiate(Component.java:1359)
 at org.jboss.seam.Component.newInstance(Component.java:2122)
 at org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts.startup(Contexts.java:304)
 at org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts.startup(Contexts.java:278)
 at org.jboss.seam.contexts.ServletLifecycle.endInitialization(ServletLifecycle.java:116)
 at org.jboss.seam.init.Initialization.init(Initialization.java:740)
 at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener.contextInitialized(SeamListener.java:36)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3972)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4467)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.start(Embedded.java:825)
 at com.staxnet.appserver.TomcatServerBase.startContainer(TomcatServerBase.java:120)
 at com.staxnet.appserver.TomcatServerBase.start(TomcatServerBase.java:190)
 at com.staxnet.appserver.SnazAppServer.main(SnazAppServer.java:89)
Jul 20, 2010 9:24:13 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javassist version conflict. I upgraded Javassist to 3.8.0.GA to solve this (add a dependency to your pom if it does not exist).